# Any thoughts on speeding up the execution of this program

Tags: java, performance

For the record this isn't my code found an tested it out and took forever to complete.
The first letter takes forever to get to letters farther down in the alphabet.
Any thoughts are greatly appreciated thanks in advance.

```
public class BruteForce {

  public static void main (String[] args) {

    System.out.println ("write your password (5 character only)");
    String password = TextIO.getlnString ();
    String word = "";

    char letters[] = new char [5];
    letters [0] = 'a';
    letters [1] = 'a';
    letters [2] = 'a'; //starts all the 5 letters with 'a'
    letters [3] = 'a';
    letters [4] = 'a';

    while (word != password) {
     //This seems like it would stop the program, but it's telling me that the variable(word) hasn't been initialized

        for (letters [0] = 'a' ; letters [0] <= 'y' ; letters [0]++) {
            word = new String (letters);
            System.out.println (word);

            for (letters [1] = 'a' ; letters [1] <= 'y' ; letters [1]++) {
                word = new String (letters);
                System.out.println (word);

                for (letters [2] = 'a' ; letters [2] <= 'y' ; letters [2]++) {
                    word = new String (letters); //nested for loops
                    System.out.println (word);

                    for (letters [3] = 'a' ; letters [3] <= 'y' ; letters [3]++) {
                        word = new String (letters);
                        System.out.println (word);

                        for (letters [4] = 'a' ; letters [4] <= 'y' ; letters [4]++) {
                            word = new String (letters);
                            System.out.println (word);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `while word != password` - you can't compare strings with `==`; use `! str1.equals(str2)`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try something like,

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
loop: for (char i = 'a'; i <= 'z'; i++) {
    for (char j = 'a'; j <= 'z'; j++) {
        for (char k = 'a'; k <= 'z'; k++) {
            for (char l = 'a'; l <= 'z'; l++) {
                for (char m = 'a'; m <= 'z'; m++) {
                    sb.append(i).append(j).append(k).append(l).append(m);
                    System.out.println(sb.toString());
                    if (sb.toString().equals(password)) {
                        break loop;
                    }
                    sb.setLength(0);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```